# DOM manipulation not be detected by Jasmine jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am using Jasmine jQuery to test a custom javascript module's AJAX request and ultimately it's post-process manipulation of the DOM, but my Jasmine test is not locating the newly manipulated elements.

The Jasmine test is as follows...

```
describe("#init", function() {
  it("should return a JSON object from the server", function() {
    loadFixtures("top_content_container.html");

    // This method will add 'div.search_result' to the 'div.top_content' container
    SC.init();

    expect($('div.top_content')).toContain('div.top_content_container');
    expect($('div.top_content')).toContain('div.search_results');

   // THIS TEST SHOULD PASS, BUT DOES NOT DETECT THE DOM UPDATES AND DOES NOT
   expect($('div.top_content div.search_result').length == 10).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Within the `SC.init()` method it adds elements to the DOM then runs an AJAX request, which returns data and injects it into the DOM.  These newly created elements match "div.search_result".

I have confirmed that all the AJAX requests are running properly and the SC library is properly injecting all the elements into the DOM; from a functionality perspective the library is working.  The problem is how to get the Jasmine test to see the updates to the DOM.  Again, I do not need help debugging the SC codebase; I need help debugging the test itself.

Do you see anything out of whack?

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is asynchronous so your Jasmine spec is probably reaching the assertion about search results before the AJAX request has received a response.  You may want to do a `jasmine.Ajax.useMock()` before calling `SC.init()` and then pass it a successful response.  You'll need [Jasmine-Ajax](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-ajax) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries like https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery will give you more power. However, a crude solution is also possible using runs/waitsFor for asynchronous queries.

```
 it("should load asynchronously", function() {

     runs(function() {
        $el = $('<div id="jasmine-insert">').appendTo('body');
        $el.load('path/file.html');
      });
      waitsFor(
        function() {  return $el.html().length > 0; }, // tested at intervals
        "html couldn't be loaded", // message on error
        500); // wait time out
      runs(function() {
        expect($('div.top_content').find('div.top_content_container').toEqual(1));
      });

  });
```